# Getting the rate of drain from a tank

Tags: calculus

A tank with a top radius of **1m**, a bottom radius of **0.5m** and a height of **2m** is initially filled with water. Water drains through a square hole of side **3cm** in the bottom.

How do I get the rate of drain,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} 
\end{equation}
of the tank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conservation of mass and constant density tells us change in volume in the tank equals change in volume out of tank.

Thinking area times velocity gives you rate of volume change out of tank, by dimensional analysis.

Bernouli s principle says

$\frac{1}{2}v^2=gh$

$v=\sqrt{2gh}$

Area=side length of square hole squared.

Keep in mind h varies with time.

Volume in tank:
$V=\frac{\pi}{3}(h+2)(r_1+\frac{h(r_2-r_1)}{2})^2-\frac{\pi}{3}2r_1^2$

So :

$A\sqrt{2gh}=\frac{dV}{dt}$

Will give you a differential equation in h as function of t.

Insert back into expression for V to get it as function of t. Differentiate to find alternative expression for derivative.